# Appcode Reformat Code JavaDoc style comments disagreeably

Tags: javadoc, appcode

AppCodes 'Reformat Code' feature formats JavaDoc comments in a disagreeable manner.

This is how I like to have the comments:

```
/**
 * blabla
 * @return blibla array bli
 */
```

but 'Reformat Code' always reformats it to

```
/**
* blabla
* @return blibla array bli
*/
- (NSArray *) bla....
```

Does anyone know how I can tell AppCode to format those comments as I like, or at least how to not touch any existing comments?

Comment: Does it add empty string after?

Comment: Where do you mean? At least at the end of the line no whitespaces or anything is inserted.

Comment: Ah, I see the difference now

Comment: This is very annoying. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: unforutnately not yet.